# PGI compilation problem in Fortran: deferred procedure creates segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, pgi

I am testing the PGI Fortran 19.10 compiler. 
And I get a `segmentation fault` after compilation with PGI when I run the file named `test.f90` ; while when I compile and run with gfortran or ifort I get no problem.

the file`test.f90`:

```
MODULE modu
IMPLICIT NONE

! Format
 type, abstract :: FormatFile
 contains
    procedure(File_open_file),nopass, deferred :: open_files
 end type FormatFile

 type, extends(FormatFile) :: FormatA
 contains
    procedure, nopass :: open_files => open_fileA
 end type FormatA

 ! Type
 type, abstract :: TypeFile
   class(FormatFile), allocatable :: format
 end type TypeFile

 type, extends(TypeFile) :: TypeB
 end type TypeB

! FileHandler
type,  public      :: FileHandler
   private
   class(TypeFile), allocatable    :: type
   contains
      procedure,  pass(fd), public  :: open_file
end type FileHandler

abstract interface
    subroutine File_open_file( fd )
       import FileHandler
       class(FileHandler), intent(inout) :: fd
    end subroutine
 end interface


CONTAINS

subroutine write_output()
   IMPLICIT NONE
   type(FileHandler) :: FileH
   !-------------------------------------------------------------------------

   print*, 'write_output: start.'
     allocate(TypeB :: FileH%type)
     allocate( FormatA :: FileH%type%format)

   call FileH%open_file()
   print*, 'write_output: end.'
end subroutine write_output

subroutine open_file( fd )
   implicit none

   class(FileHandler), intent(inout) :: fd
   !-------------------------------------------------------------------------

   print *, 'open_file: start'
   call fd%type%format%open_files(fd)
   print *, 'open_file: end'
end subroutine open_file

subroutine open_fileA( fd )
   implicit none

   class(FileHandler), intent(inout)  :: fd
   !-------------------------------------------------------------------------

   print *, 'open_fileA: start'
   !print*, 'job done'
   print *, 'open_fileA: end'
end subroutine open_fileA

end module modu


PROGRAM main_prog
USE modu

print*, "Start main"
call write_output()
print*, "End main"
END PROGRAM main_prog
```

Therefore the command `pgfortran -c test.f90  && pgfortran -o main_test test.o && ./main_test` returns me:

```
Start main
write_output: start.
open_file: start
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

While it run as expected with gfortran or ifort. Otherwise I also tested this code with the option `-Mnollvm` of the PGI compiler, and it yields the same segmentation fault.

Of course in this simple example I could remove the intermediate object `TypeFile`, which remove the segmentation fault problem ; but I really need it in some bigger project.

So am I missing something ? or is it a bug of the PGI compiler ?